# HTML In Concatenation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concatenation

```
SELECT
    EB.first_name AS FNAME,
    EB.emp_id AS EID,
    CONCAT(EB.first_name,' ',EB.mid_name,' ',EB.last_name) AS FULLNAME,
    EB.id AS ID,
    ESAL.dept_id AS DEPT_ID,
    DATE_FORMAT(EB.dob,'%D %b %y') AS DOB,
    EB.email_per AS EPER,
    EB.mobile_per AS MOBPER,
    EB.father_name AS FATHER,
    EB.mother_name AS MOTHER,
    EB.sex AS SEX,
    EB.email_office AS EOF,
    EB.mobile_office AS MOBO,
    EB.blood_group AS BG,
    CONCAT(EB.id_type,' : ',EB.id_no) AS ID,
    CONCAT(EB.present_addr,'<br>',EB.present_city_id,'<br>',EB.present_state_id) AS PRA
FROM mtc_employee_master EB
LEFT JOIN mtc_employee_education_master EE  ON EE.emp_tbl_id = EB.id
LEFT JOIN mtc_employee_experience_master EEXP ON EEXP.emp_tbl_id = EB.id
LEFT JOIN mtc_employee_salary_master ESAL ON ESAL.emp_tbl_id = EB.id WHERE EB.id=".$data['id']."
```

What I am trying to do to embed HTML content in concat of MySQL..is it possible?? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, even if it not the best solution...

```
SELECT CONCAT('<p>', now(), '</p>') as html;
+----------------------------+
| html                       |
+----------------------------+
| <p>2015-04-27 13:12:33</p> |
+----------------------------+
```

and you have already done this in:

`CONCAT(EB.present_addr,'<br>',EB.present_city_id,'<br>',EB.present_state_id,)`

 but you should delete comma:
`CONCAT(EB.present_addr,'<br>',EB.present_city_id,'<br>',EB.present_state_id)`